# When can we omit "while" in a sentence? "I run {while} listening to music"

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

I was given the examples of omitting "while" below:

> I iron clothes watching t.v.
> I run listening to music.

But was told they are both wrong. But I can't see why? It's clear the two activities are happening at the same time. It's clear that the clothing isn't watching the t.v. so why is it wrong?

Comment: They aren't wrong. Bear in mind though that watching TV and listening to music are really gerund phrases.

Comment: This question seems perfectly clear to me and should not be closed s "needs details or clarity".

Comment: Who said that these are wrong? That is, what sort of person: teacher, friend, co-worker, boss, or what?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences:

> - I iron clothes watching t.v.

> - I run listening to music.

are both grammatically valid. Neither is "wrong". Some fluent speakers might think that they would be clearer with the word "while" included. But I think that both are reasonably clear as they stand.